# how to call netmiko ConnectHandler from another py page and execute it only with button in choose

Tags: python, tkinter, netmiko

I need to be able to call the script from the scripter.py by choosing it from the drop-down list and clicking a button to run it and get the output in the same window. so I have 2 main problems the first is how to call netmiko ConnectHandler from another py page and execute it only with button in choose the problem is when I run the main.py it executes the scripter.py automatically after that the tkinter is opens

the second is a don't know how to export the output from scripter.py to the main.py and show it in tkinter

So my (scripter.py) looks like

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
    
fortinet_device = {
    'device_type': 'fortinet',
    'ip': 'X.X.X.X',
    'username': 'Username',
    'password': 'Password'
}
    
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**fortinet_device)
    
cmd = ['get sys arp']
output = ''
for command in cmd:
    output += net_connect.send_command(command)
    
print(output)
```

And my main page is (main.py)

```py
from tkinter import *
from scripter import cmd

master = Tk(className="Test")
master.geometry("300x300")

def func(selected_item):
    print(repr(selected_item.strip()))

#************main_menu menu***********
main_menu = StringVar(master)
    
#***********dependent_menu menu*********
dependent_menu = StringVar(master)

#************main_menu values**************
show_arp = cmd 
show_add = 'show firewall address'

#***********dependent_menu values************
grep = '|grep'

# main_menu default value
main_menu.set(show_arp)

# dependent_menu default value
dependent_menu.set(grep)

#************main_menu**************
w = OptionMenu(master, main_menu, show_arp, show_add, "three")
w.pack(side=TOP)

#**************dependent_menu***************
s = OptionMenu(master, dependent_menu, grep)
s.pack(side=LEFT)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to put the code inside `scripter.py` inside a function, for example:

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

def get_sys_arp():
    fortinet_device = {
        'device_type': 'fortinet',
        'ip': 'X.X.X.X',
        'username': 'username',
        'password': 'password'
    }
        
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**fortinet_device)
        
    cmd = ['get sys arp']
    output = ''
    for command in cmd:
        output += net_connect.send_command(command)
        
    print(output)
```

Then import this function inside `main.py` and execute it when the corresponding item in `OptionMenu` is selected:

```py
from tkinter import *
from scripter import get_sys_arp   # import the function from scripter

master = Tk(className="Test")
master.geometry("300x300")

def func(selected_item):
    print(repr(selected_item.strip()))
    if selected_item == 'show arp':
        get_sys_arp()  # execute the function

#************main_menu menu***********
main_menu = StringVar(master)

#***********dependent_menu menu*********
dependent_menu = StringVar(master)

#************main_menu values**************
show_arp = 'show arp'   # item text for running get_sys_arp()
show_add = 'show firewall address'

#***********dependent_menu values************
grep = '|grep'

# main_menu default value
main_menu.set(show_arp)

# dependent_menu default value
dependent_menu.set(grep)

#************main_menu**************
# add command=func to execute func() when a item is selected
w = OptionMenu(master, main_menu, show_arp, show_add, "three", command=func)
w.pack(side=TOP)

#**************dependent_menu***************
s = OptionMenu(master, dependent_menu, grep)
s.pack(side=LEFT)

mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you it did work fine. is there any way to send the scripter.py output to the textbox in the main.py?

Comment: @HassanKidan You can replace `print(output)` by `return output` inside `get_sys_arp()` and then insert the output returned into a textbox inside `func()`.

Comment: added def out_to_gui():
    print(f"{get_sys_arp.get()}")

Comment: and replace print(output) by return output

Comment: added to main textbox = Text(leftframe, func(out_to_gui()))

Comment: get the erorr       print(f"{get_sys_arp.get()}")
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: The error message is obviously telling you what is the issue, why do you call `get()` on a function?  BTW, you better raise a new question on this issue.